# When hovered title is not been shown

Tags: html, jquery, hover

I am making a website in which I have used the hover function of jquery.
I have used the hover function in 5 places on my website. But when I hover on any of them the main heading is not being shown except the last one.

[image: image1]

In this image, I hovered on a div and I am not able to see the main heading that I want to show to everyone. Similar in these images:-

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

Now in the 5th image, the main heading is been shown:-
[image: image5]

Please help why is this happening.

And I also want to know what should I do so that when I put the cursor on the bar which is been showed when hovered to click on the links on it.

code:-

```
        <a href="" id="men" class="h">MEN</a></h4>

        <a href="" id="women" class="h">WOMEN</a></h4>

        <a href="" class="h" id="kids">KIDS</a></h4>

        <a href="" class="h" id="homeliving">HOME & LIVING</a></h4>

        <a href="" class="h" id="offers">OFFERS</a></h4>
    </div>
<div class="items hidden">
        <p id="topwear" class="hidden">MEN</p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Jackets</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden">
        <p id="indian" class="hidden">WOMEN</p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden">
        <p id="boys" class="hidden">KIDS</p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden">
        <p id="bed" class="hidden">HOME & LIVING</p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden">
        <p id="kurta" class="hidden">OFFERS</p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
        <p class="para hidden"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>

</div><script type="text/javascript">

    $("#men").hover(function() {

        $(".items").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#topwear").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".para").toggleClass("hidden");
        
    });
    
    $("#women").hover(function() {

        $(".items").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#indian").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".para").toggleClass("hidden");
        
    });

    $("#kids").hover(function() {

        $(".items").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#boys").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".para").toggleClass("hidden");
        
    });

    $("#homeliving").hover(function() {

        $(".items").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#bed").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".para").toggleClass("hidden");
        
    });

    $("#offers").hover(function() {

        $(".items").toggleClass("hidden");
        $("#kurta").toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".para").toggleClass("hidden");
        
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed html and jquery, please try this.

you can check it from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maulik_bafalipara/unzkvqme/29/)

```
<div>
  <a href="" id="men" class="h menu_link">MEN</a>
  <a href="" id="women" class="h menu_link">WOMEN</a>
  <a href="" class="h menu_link" id="kids">KIDS</a>
  <a href="" class="h menu_link" id="homeliving">HOME & LIVING</a>
  <a href="" class="h menu_link" id="offers">OFFERS</a>
</div>
<div class="items hidden" data-target_id="men">
  <p id="topwear">MEN</p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Jackets</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden" data-target_id="women">
  <p id="indian">WOMEN</p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden" data-target_id="kids">
  <p id="boys">KIDS</p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden" data-target_id="homeliving">
  <p id="bed">HOME & LIVING</p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>
<div class="items hidden" data-target_id="offers">
  <p id="kurta">OFFERS</p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">T-Shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Casual shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Formal shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweat shirts</a></p>
  <p class="para"><a href="">Sweaters</a></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".menu_link").hover(function() {
    target_id = $(this).attr('id')
    $('.items:not([data-target_id="' + target_id + '"])').addClass('hidden')
    $('.items[data-target_id="' + target_id + '"]').removeClass('hidden')
  })
  $("body").hover(function(e) {
    var menu_contain = $(".items");
    if (!menu_contain.is(e.target) && menu_contain.has(e.target).length === 1) {
     $('.items').addClass('hidden')
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It helps me, but not fully.
now when i remove my cursor from the div now the bar is no more hidden which i dont want.
i want that when i hover on the div to show the bar now when the bar is been shown when my cursor go over the bar to click on a link it does not hide.But when my cursor is not on the bar it should be hidden.
Please help.

Comment: @Abhinavvijaywargiya i have updated my code please check it.

Comment: Thank You it solved my most of the problem.But now when we hover the div the bar is been shown but to hide the bar we have to put our cursor on the bar first and then remove our cursor from the bar.That i don't want.

Comment: I have updated the code please check it https://jsfiddle.net/maulik_bafalipara/unzkvqme/69/

Comment: if working for you then please accept the answer.